# Tensorflow: The prediction of my model is always the same

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have trained a deep CNN that predicts a one-dimentional array and saved the weight variables in the format of `.ckpt`. But when I give the model new inputs, it always outputs the same array. I have already check the preprocess of the inputs and I'm sure they are alright. Here is the code of my prediction.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

filename = os.listdir("D:/project/test datasets/image")
new_dir  = "D:/project/test datasets/"

for img in filename:
    img=os.path.splitext(img)[0]
    xs = pd.read_csv(new_dir+img+'.csv',index_col=0)
    xs = xs.values.flatten()
    xs = np.expand_dims(xs,0)

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, 'model.ckpt')  

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()  
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")  
    keep_prob = graph.get_tensor_by_name("keep_prob:0")
    y_conv = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_conv:0")

    print(sess.run(y_conv,feed_dict={x:xs,keep_prob:1.0}))
```

And I also find that when I add the code statement `y_conv = tf.constant(0)` in the end of the loop, the following output will all be `0`, which means my prediction `y_conv` doesn't update in each loop.

I have no idea where is wrong. Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you passing ```y_conv = tf.constant(0) ?```   Is ```y_conv```  output of your network ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. Please can you try in the below format

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(savefile)
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(savedir))

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_x:0")
    result = graph.get_tensor_by_name("result:0")

    feed_dict = {input_x: x_data,}

    predictions = result.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind advice. I have already found the reason as my model is under-fitting. And there is nothing wrong with these codes.

Comment: If you like my advice, kindly accept my answer and upvote it.Thank you.